# best design practice for JSPs

Tags: jsp

We are having the requirement where we have 5 different instances of the application.
 Now we are trying to revamp the architecture in such a way that we have single code base and different configuration files for different environment.
We want to design our JSP Pages in such a way that we can avoid IF and else statements to large extent and through some means we want to hide a particular feature if user has not configured it for that instance.
Please let me know the best possible ways of achieving it.
I was thinking on these lines

1) Have div tag for the features which are configurable.

2) give div tag a class.

3) through beans change the class names so that it generates toggling effect.

4) By this I can avoid the IF and else condition..

I am not sure if my approach is ok or not and what is the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of including all possible content in the HTML, even if some (or most) of it is not needed at all, and just hiding it from view by means of CSS, then that sounds like a bad idea (especially if the content is big and/or expensive to create). Twice so if the content that needs to be hidden should not be accessible to the user at all (because she did not pay for the features).

Comment: yes, thats a good point u made.. so what should be the approach then.

Comment: You need to think about the problem you want to solve. This is not about avoiding if/else.

Comment: the problem is i want to have a single JSP for all instances and based on configuration properties of each instance it should render accordingly.I can read the properties file and based on that i need to add if n else statements for not rendering some content which is not configured for the instance. is that the only solution or a better design aproach can be taken.

Comment: You do not want a single JSP for all instances. You may want a single war file for all instances.